# calculating average for time in hh:mm format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of time in hh:mm format and am trying to figure out how to properly calculate the average.

I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yVMK/1/) that does something similar but has miliseconds too which I don't need and I am having hard time converting it to what I need.

```
var times= [ '00:00:03.00', '00:00:05.00', '00:00:02.00', '00:00:06.00'],
    date = 0,
    result = '';
function offsetify(t){
    return t < 10 ? '0' + t : t;
}
for(var x = 0; x < times.length; x++ ) {
    var tarr = times[x].split(':');
    date += new Date(0, 0, 0, tarr[0], tarr[1], tarr[2].split('.')[0], tarr[2].split('.')[1]).getTime();   
}
var avg = new Date(date/times.length);
result = offsetify(avg.getHours()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getMinutes()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getSeconds()) + '.' + offsetify(avg.getMilliseconds());
document.write(result);
```

can someone please help to modify this so it would provide correct average for array that looks like this:

```
var times= [ '00:03', '00:13', '02:10', '01:00']
```

thanks!

Comment: Just remove the parameters to the new Date() that are beyond tarr[1].  The parameters to new Date(), past the year and month, are all optional as the MDN documentation will show.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: yes, I figured it out thanks. :) [http://jsfiddle.net/3yVMK/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/3yVMK/8/)

Comment: Suggest you delete the question then so others don't waste their time

Comment: actually i just played around with the numbers and I think I am getting wrong average result. Can you please double check this [http://jsfiddle.net/3yVMK/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/3yVMK/9/)

Comment: what output are you expecting for the given array?

Comment: if you look at the last fiddle array that I posted, 7 hours are equal to 420 minutes so if (420 + 13 + 6 + 6)/4 = 111.25, which I think is 1.9 hrs.
Wouldn't it make sense for the output to be then 01:09? I am not sure where 51 is coming from in 01.51

Comment: Maybe I am converting it wrong in my head

Comment: the `111.25` are minutes don't confuse it, take `60 minutes (1 Hour)` out of it **111.25 - 60** leaves remaining **51.25 minutes**  which sums up to 1 Hour and 51 minutes i.e `01:51` which is DAMN! accurate so you are doing it right, just confused between `100%` and `1 Hour`. @coder

Comment: ok thank you!  Appreciate you verifying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who didn't see it in the comments, I have the answer I needed here:

```
var times= [ '00:13', '00:06', '07:00', '00:06'],
    date = 0,
    result = '';
function offsetify(t){
    return t < 10 ? '0' + t : t;
}
for(var x = 0; x < times.length; x++ ) {
    var tarr = times[x].split(':');
    date += new Date(0, 0, 0, tarr[0], tarr[1]).getTime();   
}
var avg = new Date(date/times.length);
result = offsetify(avg.getHours()) + ':' + offsetify(avg.getMinutes());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to tell you about a way you can convert time to a good value for calculations using time input element

the input is smart enough to figure out that if you send in `00:03` or `00:00:03` it will parse the hh:mm or hh:mm:ss as correct

```js
var i = document.createElement('input')
i.type = 'time'
i.value = '00:01:03.00'
console.log(i.valueAsNumber) // Will help you calculate avg time easier
i.valueAsNumber = 3000
console.log(i.value) // a way to precent it in a readable way
```

This is how i would calculate it... without timezone offset or something like that that is done in the jsfiddle example

```js
var sum = 0
var times = [ '00:00:03', '00:00:13', '00:02:10', '00:01:00']
var input = document.createElement('input')
input.type = 'time'

sum = times.reduce(function(prev, time) {
  input.value = time
  return prev + input.valueAsNumber
},0)

input.valueAsNumber = sum / times.length // avg time

console.log(input.value)
```

Comment: This is a nice technique but FWIW browser support for `valueAsNumber` is incomplete; it returns NaN on read and throws an InvalidStateError on write in current Safari as well as IE and Edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/669685/

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that you need to deal with mm:ss format, this code may work for you:

```
var times = [ '00:03', '00:13', '02:10', '01:00'];
var totalSeconds = 0;
times.forEach(function(element){
    var timeParts = element.split(":"); //Separate  mm ss

    var secs = Number(timeParts[0]) * 60 + Number(timeParts [1]); 
    totalSeconds += secs;  
})

console.log(totalSeconds);
var avgSeconds = totalSeconds / times.length;
console.log(avgSeconds);
```

I found a way to accomplish this getting around the milliseconds issue by splitting the "time" strings:

```
var times= [ '00:00:03.00', '00:00:05.00', '00:00:02.00', '00:00:06.00']
var totalSeconds = 0;
times.forEach(function(element){
    var timeParts = element.split(":"); //Separate HH mm ss.ff
    var secParts = timeParts[2].split("."); //Separate ss ff
    var secs = Number(timeParts[0]) * 3600 + Number(timeParts[1]) * 60 + 
    Number(secParts [0]); //3600: Seconds in an hour - 60: seconds in a minute
    totalSeconds += secs;  
})

console.log(totalSeconds); //16
var avgSeconds = totalSeconds / times.length;
console.log(avgSeconds);  //4
```